# IBM Mobilefirst: Is there a way I can send a push notification to deviceid irrespective of user

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I want to subscribe multiple users to a device for push notification in MFP. which i assume is not possible.

So what I want to do is i want to send my notification on the basis of deviceid ignoring user. Is this possible.

I see two methods which send notification to a device, but they still need userid is what i see.

```
WL.Server.notifyDevice(userSubscription, deviceId, notification);
WL.Server.notifyDeviceSubscription(deviceSubscription, notificationOptions)
```

Is there any other way, Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can send push notification targeted to deviceId using multiple ways.

1. You can use `sendMessage` API where you can specify deviceIds in Target Parameter. In this case only those deviceIds will receive the notification.

   - More Details about API : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html#sendMessage
2. `Send Message` REST API where you need to add target as deviceIds.

The following is the payload example.

```
{
  "message" : {
    "alert" : "Test message",
  },
  "target" : {
    "deviceIds" : [ "MyDeviceId1", ... ]
  },
}
```

- More details about API : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_send_message_post.html

Comment: Thank you  Vittal.

Comment: Vittal I have a small issue here i am sending the notification as you mentioned above . But when i receive the notification its calling onMessage() method but the props and payload of this method are empty i think i have to give it a tag name can you help what tag name can i give. How should i avoid this issue.

Comment: @Bender Tag names are meant for tag based push notifications. Seems to be you are not passing any parameters other than message. Refer payload/properties example [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_send_message_post.html) .

Comment: I am sending 
        notificationOptions.target.deviceIds =deviceIds ;   and  notificationOptions.message.alert = notificationText; I am receiving the notification i cant see the notification in the notification bar but the message is empty in onmessage method.